# Google Home app not letting me teach it my voice

Tags: google-assistant

Whenever I try to setup my voice when prompted in the app it just gets stuck on the subsequent please wait screen

> [image]
>   [image: 'please wait' screen].

This is on a Samsung S8.

Tried clearing the data on the app, restarting the phone, reinstalling the app. Nothing makes a difference.

I've been able to complete this step on my wife's phone for her account, so it doesn't seem to be a network issue.

Any ideas what's stopping it progressing through this voice learning?

Comment: I have the same problem....on a S8. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @daw9948 not exactly. I had to find my old phone (S6) and set it all up that way instead. Still don't know why the S8 doesn't let you do it.